# What is the value of $a_1a_2\cdots a_{2019}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, recurrence-relations, telescopic-series

Let $a_1=\frac 34$ and for any $n\geq2$ $4a_n=4a_{n-1}+\frac {2n+1}{1^3+2^3+\cdots n^3 }$. What is the value of $a_1a_2\cdots a_{2019}$?

I tried $1^3+2^3+\cdots +n^3=\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ and

I wroted

$4(a_n-a_{n-1})=\frac {2n+1}{1^3+2^3+\cdots n^3 }$.
Then

$$4(a_2-a_1)=\frac {2×2+1}{1^3+2^3 }\\ 4(a_3-a_2)=\frac {2×3+1}{1^3+2^3+3^3 }\\ \cdots$$

When we add the equations side by side, the left side becomes simpler.  But the right side gets complicated. I tried to find closed form for $a_n$ but it seems very complicated.

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction decomposition? That might give you a telescoping product.

Comment: Using that sum of cubes formula, the recurrence can be written as $a_n = a_{n-1}+\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$. This should simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $$a_n - a_{n-1} = \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} = \frac{(n+1)^2 - n^2}{n^2 (n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}. \tag{1}$$  So $$a_m - a_1 = \sum_{n=2}^m a_n - a_{n-1} =  \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{(m+1)^2},$$ hence $$a_m = 1 - \frac{1}{(m+1)^2} = \frac{m(m+2)}{(m+1)^2}. \tag{2}$$  Therefore, $$\prod_{m=1}^{2019} a_m = \prod_{m=1}^{2019} \frac{m}{m+1} \frac{m+2}{m+1} = \frac{2021}{4040}.$$

Comment: Mathematica tells me $2021/4040$, are you sure about your answer? (If you go through the final product, only one of the $m+1$ gets cancelled when $m=1$.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi the last part of the answer is technically wrong or methodically?

Comment: @User Well, you shouldn't ask me, you should check it for yourself to understand the details. But everything in the answer appears correct up to the very last equality.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi your answer is correct. What is mathematica ?

Comment: @user It's a software for computer algebra.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I made a mistake at the very end where I forgot to count a factor of $2$ since the intermediate calculation should be $$\frac{2019! 2022! / 2!}{(2019!)^2}.$$  This has now been fixed.